# How do I enable the Developer menu in Settings for Apple TV 4th Gen?

Tags: tvos, developer-tools, apple-tv

I've seen a developer menu in the Settings app for iPhone and iPad. Recently I also got it to show up in the Settings app for my Apple TV 4 but I can't seem to remember how now. I ask because I enabled a feature that displays the refresh rate and bitrate for audio and video on the top left corner in yellow letters while beta testing tvOS 10.1 but when tvOS 10.1 GM was released, my Apple TV auto updated before I could turn it off but the yellow letters persists in the top left corner and the developer menu is gone. I added the new 10.1.1 beta profile so I could try to get the developer menu to show in the Settings app but so far it hasn't appeared on it's own. I know I could restore my Apple TV but I don't want to do that because I don't have a way to backup my app data and I know there's a way to enable that menu to show again I just don't know how. If you're familiar with the menu, it also allows you to create a custom "Service Provider" for the TV app and add your own URL for authentication as well. It's a menu item that shows up on the bottom of the Settings app. Does anyone know how to enable this menu?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Settings -> Developer options -> Scroll down to Media service testing and Enable Playback HUD

Answer (score 5):

If it is an ATV4, hook to Mac w/USB C, open Xcode & the developer menu will appear under Settinga on Apple TV.  Xcode is the trigger to make this menu visible.  All you have to do is open it.